# Automation Anywhere takes high time to run script

Tags: javascript, rpa, automationanywhere

I'm using Automation anywhere for RPA but when i call, run script it takes huge time to run a js script even for returning a normal string without any complex code.

Is it normal? or any way to increase speed for script running.

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen with all commands too? What is the AA Client version? Try to add a small delay before the run script command.

Comment: @KhaledMostafaMe no it won't happen with other command s,  it's taking time to call script.

Comment: What is the version of the AA Client?

Comment: Did you try to add a small delay before the run script command?

Comment: @KhaledMostafaMe Yes i tried it just added some more delay.
and version is AAE11.3.0.0

Comment: What is code you are trying? how you are calling it in AA?

Comment: How much is the difference between Manual Execution and Through AA